# How to capture the errors in node.js using uncaughtException

Tags: node.js, error-handling

In my application i want to create own module to capture my application error using uncaughtException.If i create uncaughtException in same module means its capturing errors but if i create that uncaughtException in separate module.Then call that  module means its not capturing erros.Can anyone help me to fix this issue.

module1.js

```
   var errorModule=require('./module2');
   var err = new Error('Something went terribly wrong');
   errorModule.captureError(err);
```

module2.js

```
  module.exports.captureError=function(err){

     process.on('uncaughtException', function(err) {

       console.log(err);

   });



 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
// module1.js
var errorModule=require('./module2');
errorModule.captureErrors();    
throw Error('Something went terribly wrong');

// module2.js
module.exports.captureErrors = function() {
  process.on('uncaughtException', function(err) {
    console.log('an error occurred', err);
  });
};
```

A few things to notice:

- `process.on('uncaughtException', ...)` installs an event handler to catch uncaught exceptions; your code tries to pass an error to it, but that seems to defeat what you're writing (*'to capture my application error using uncaughtException'*);
- Uncaught exceptions are errors which are *thrown* (`throw Error(...)`);

If you want the code in *your* `module1` to work, `module2` needs to look like this:

```
module.exports.captureError = function(err) {
  console.log(err);
};
```

But that has nothing to do with `uncaughtException`.